Mapply for rows of two matrice arguments and another matrix argument
I have two matrices $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ of the same dimensions. I want to calculate a weighted inner products of rows of $A$ and $B$ with the weight matrix $W$ using the following function
X = matrix(1:9,3,3)
Y = matrix(1,3,3)
W = matrix(1,3,3)

inn.prod = function(x,y,W){
  print(W)
  a = matrix(x,1,length(x))
  b = matrix(y,length(y),1)
  return(a%*%W%*%b)
}


To apply this functions for all rows of $A$ and $B$, I want to use
mapply(inn.prod,asplit(X,1),asplit(Y,1),W)


but unfortunately, mapply does not pass W through - print(W) shows 1 and an error message
Error in a %*% W : non-conformable arguments. 


I also tried
Q = list(W,W,W)
mapply(inn.prod,asplit(X,1),asplit(Y,1),simplify2array(Q))


but got the same error. Any idea how to make this work? Thanks!

I'm guessing this is julia?

@Mark: No, this is R.

You may not want to vectorize over W, try mapply(inn.prod, asplit(X, 1), asplit(Y, 1), MoreArgs = list(W)).
